# Realm: sorting by property in child object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My Show object looks like this:

```
class Show: RLMObject {
    dynamic var venue: Venue?
}
```

and my Venue object:

```
class Venue: RLMObject {
    dynamic var title = ""
}
```

I need to be able to sort my Show objects by their Venue object's titles. I tried the following but got an error:

```
allShowsByLocation = Show.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("venue.title", ascending: true)
```

The error is: Invalid sort column', reason: 'Column named '(null)' not found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Realm doesn't yet support sorting `RLMResults` by a sub-property. As a work-around, you could query for `Venue`s and return its linking object for each index:

```
allVenues = Venue.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("title", ascending: true)

func showAtIndex(index: UInt) -> Show {
  return (allVenues[index] as Venue).linkingObjectsOfClass("Show", forProperty: "venue")
}
```

Or you could simply add a `venueTitle` property to your `Show` model which would then allow your query to work:

```
allShowsByLocation = Show.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("venueTitle", ascending: true)
```

You can also subscribe to [GitHub issue #1199](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1199) to follow our progress on supporting sub-property sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sad when Realm not support this feature.
I try another solution for this issue and it work well

- copy all object in RLMResults to an array
- Sort sub property of object in Array using compare

Comment: But this isn't auto-updating